# Magento 2.3: Automatically add HTML tags in a Static Block after save

Tags: magento2.3, static-block, html, wysiwyg, static-content

**Automatically adding HTML tags in a Static Block after save**

When saving static block from admin then after saving static block it is automatically adding HTML tags

How can we solve it so that it will not add HTML body tags after saving static blocks ?

Please check screenshot
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @sumeet bajaj The above-mentioned issue was not reproduced in Magento2.3. Please check if you have any 3rd party extensions related to the static block form page or static block save functionality.

Comment: It seems to be a JavaScript thing, When saving a block, the HTML tags are placed around it when the page is reloaded, but doesn't show it in the database before you save it for a second time.